# Will a UIView release its subviews in Cocoa Touch?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, memory-management, uiview

If I create a UIControl at runtime and add it to a view (via addSubview:), will the view release it or am I supposed to do that?

Here's an example code:

```
-(IBAction) cloneMe: (id) sender{

    if (!currentY) {
        currentY = [sender frame].origin.y;
    }

    UIButton *clone = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    CGRect cloneFrame = [sender frame];
    cloneFrame.origin.y += currentY + cloneFrame.size.height + 30;
    clone.frame = cloneFrame;
    [clone setTitle:@"I'm a clone" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [[sender superview] addSubview:clone];

    currentY = cloneFrame.origin.y + cloneFrame.size.height;


}
```

Comment: Could you give a brief example of the code you have?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect]` gives you an already autoreleased object.
That means you don't "own" the object and therefore you don't have the responsibility of releasing it.

If you were retaining it, then you would be explicitly saying that you want to keep this object for yourself, which means you would be taking the responsibility of releasing it.

The `UIView` will retain it's subviews, so it's the `UIView`'s responsibility to release them. The `UIView` will release it's subviews when itself is dealloc'ed, or when the subviews are removed from the superview.

Basically, if you didn't `alloc/init`, `new`, `copy` or `retain` an object, then it's not your object and you are not responsible for releasing it. You don't have to worry about it, whatever object that owns the object (in your case the `UIView`) will release it when it's done with it.

Answer (score 1):

When you `addSubview:` the receiver retains the argument, and releases it when you remove it via one of the methods that does.

Comment: So I should autorelease it, I guess.